# Calculating Average Function In Python From Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, average

I need to be able calculate the average of the weights in a dictionary. This also needs to be a function. Here is the code I have

```
animal=dict()
animal['1']={'ID': '21012', 'plot':4, 'year':'1993', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 42, 'hindfoot': 36, 'tag':'1EA0F9'}
animal['2']={'ID':'22012', 'plot':4, 'year':'1995', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 31, 'hindfoot': 37, 'tag':'0D373C'}
animal['3']={'ID': '23012', 'plot':17, 'year':'1996', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 25, 'hindfoot': 37, 'tag':'64C6CC'}
animal['4']={'ID': '24012','plot':21, 'year':'1996', 'species': 'PP', 'weight': 26, 'hindfoot': 22, 'tag':'1F511A'}
animal['5']={'ID': '25012', 'plot':22, 'year':'1997', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 53, 'hindfoot': 35, 'tag':'2624'}
animal['6']={'ID': '26012', 'plot':17, 'year':'1997', 'species': 'OT', 'weight': 14, 'hindfoot': 18, 'tag':'2863'}
animal['7']={'ID': '27012', 'plot':18, 'year':'1997', 'species': 'OT', 'weight': 23, 'hindfoot': 21, 'tag':'2913'}
animal['8']={'ID': '28012', 'plot':13, 'year':'1998', 'species': 'OT', 'weight': 36, 'hindfoot': 19, 'tag':'2997'}
animal['9']={'ID': '29012', 'plot':6, 'year':'1999', 'species': 'PM', 'weight': 20, 'hindfoot': 20, 'tag':'406'}
animal['10']={'ID': '30000', 'plot':14, 'year':'2000', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 41, 'hindfoot': 34, 'tag':'156'}

result=dict()

def calc_avg(r):
    if all(isinstance(x, numbers.Number) for x in r["weight"]):
        print a["title"],":", sum(r["weight"])/float(len(r["weight"]))
        return

import numbers    
calc_avg(animal.items)
```

Comment: What problems are you having?  What is your specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're assuming you can produce a list of the animal weights by calling `r["weight"]` (whatever `r` may be) - this cannot be done so simply with python dictionaries.  If you want to use such a technique, you might look into more complex data structures like a [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html).

But I'll assume you want to keep using your dictionary as is.  First, I'll recommend you pass the entire dictionary `animals` instead of the calling producing key, value pairs with `animal.items()` (note that the way you have it passes the *function* and not the dictionary values).

Second, you can test whether an object is a number by simply calling `isinstance(someObject, (int, long, float))` - the advantage here is that testing against `numbers.Number` could allow complex numbers, which would not be a valid weight (presumably) - plus is clearer.

Putting these together (omitting `a["title"]` since it's not included in the code):

def calc_avg(r):
        if all(isinstance(x["weight"], (int, long, float)) for x in r.values()):
            print sum(x["weight"] for x in r.values()) / float(len(r))

```
calc_avg(animal)
```

---

To improve on this, there's no reason you need a dictionary to store these values when a simple list could suffice.  Further, rather than checking whether **all** weights are valid, you could average only those with valid weights.

```
animal = [
    {'ID': '21012', 'plot':4, 'year':'1993', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 42, 'hindfoot': 36, 'tag':'1EA0F9'},
    {'ID':'22012', 'plot':4, 'year':'1995', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 31, 'hindfoot': 37, 'tag':'0D373C'},
    {'ID': '23012', 'plot':17, 'year':'1996', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 25, 'hindfoot': 37, 'tag':'64C6CC'},
    {'ID': '24012','plot':21, 'year':'1996', 'species': 'PP', 'weight': 26, 'hindfoot': 22, 'tag':'1F511A'},
    {'ID': '25012', 'plot':22, 'year':'1997', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 53, 'hindfoot': 35, 'tag':'2624'},
    {'ID': '26012', 'plot':17, 'year':'1997', 'species': 'OT', 'weight': 14, 'hindfoot': 18, 'tag':'2863'},
    {'ID': '27012', 'plot':18, 'year':'1997', 'species': 'OT', 'weight': 23, 'hindfoot': 21, 'tag':'2913'},
    {'ID': '28012', 'plot':13, 'year':'1998', 'species': 'OT', 'weight': 36, 'hindfoot': 19, 'tag':'2997'},
    {'ID': '29012', 'plot':6, 'year':'1999', 'species': 'PM', 'weight': 20, 'hindfoot': 20, 'tag':'406'},
    {'ID': '30000', 'plot':14, 'year':'2000', 'species': 'DM', 'weight': 41, 'hindfoot': 34, 'tag':'156'}
]

def calc_avg(r):
    valid_weights = [x["weight"] for x in r if isinstance(x["weight"], (int, long, float))]
    print(sum(valid_weights) / float(len(valid_weights)))

calc_avg(animal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't iterating through the list correctly.

You're trying to iterate through `r['weight']`. There is no `r['weight']`. You passed in `animal.items` (which should actually be `animal.items()`), which (if you'd called the function) is a list of `(key, value)` pairs in the dictionary. I'm thinking it actually would've been better to pass in `animal.values()`, which is just the values (so you won't get stuff like `('0', {...})`).

If you pass in `animal.values()`, you'll be getting a list of dictionaries. Each of those dictionaries *does* have a `'weight'` key, but the list itself does not, so you can't iterate through `r['weight']`. What you need to do is iterate through `r` itself. Each item you get in the iteration has the key you're looking for, so it'll look like:

```
    if all(isinstance(x['weight'], numbers.Number) for x in r):
        avg = sum(x['weight'] for x in r) / float( len( r ) )
```

A few more issues:

- Why is there a random `result` dict that you don't use?
- Where does `a['title']` come from?
- I'd move the `import` to the top, or at least above where you define `calc_avg`.